# SecureSocial doesn't work with Java action in play framework

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.2, securesocial

I used the following annotation but even i dont login, i still can open the "apply" page instead of redirecting me to the login page. How can i fix this?

```
@securesocial.core.java.SecureSocial.UserAwareAction
public static Result apply() {
   return ok(apply.render());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

UserAwareAction allows invocation even if the user is not authenticated. Use SecuredAction instead.